# For which values of L does the vector [l,3,-5] belong to span {[1,0,-2],[-3,1,7]?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. So far I have created the system of equations

$c_1 -3c_2 = l$;
        $c_2 = 3$;
$-2c_1 + 7c_2 = -5$.

However, I cannot figure out how to solve the set of equations without knowing $l$.

Edit: put 5 in title instead of -5

Comment: Replace $c_2=3$ in the third equation.

Comment: Substitute $1 c_2 = 3$ into the last equation to figure are $c_1$. Then substitute both into the first equation to obtain $\ell$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik duh, No idea how I missed that. Thanks a lot, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To find the values of *L* in which the vector $[L, 3, 5]$ is in the span of the vectors $[1, 0, -2]$ and $[-3, 1, 7]$, you must first ask yourself what it means for a vector to be a member of a spanning set.

In general, let $c_1, c_2, ... , c_k$ be a set of vectors. Then $Span${$c_1, c_2, ... , c_k$} is just the set of every possible linear combination of those vectors. In other words, $Span${$c_1, c_2, ... , c_k$} = {$λ_1c_1 + λ_2c_2 + ... + λ_kc_k : λ_1, λ_2, ..., λ_k ∈ℝ$}.

Now in our case, we are talking about $Span${$[1, 0, -,2], [-3, 1, 7]$}. So if the vector $[L, 3, 5]$ is in our spanning set, it must mean that $[L, 3, 5] = x[1, 0, -2] + y[-3, 1, 7]$ for some real numbers *x* and *y*. If you ignore the first columns of each vector, you can see that $[3, 5] = x[0, -2] + y[1, 7]$.

Note that y = 3. Thus, it must be that 5 = -2x + 7y implies that 5 = -2x + 7(3). Solve for x, and you get x = 8.

Looking back at our original vector equation, we see that $[L, 3, 5] = x[1, 0, -2] + y[-3, 1, 7]$ must imply that $[L, 3, 5] = 8[1, 0, -2] + 3[-3, 1, 7]$ since we *know* our values of *x* and *y*

Finally, looking at the first column only, we see that L = 8(1) + 3(-3) = -1.

Comment: There's something wrong with the last sentence of your second paragraph  ! Typo in your definition of span.

Comment: Those should be plus signs, not commas.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- (1) First prove that$[1,0,-2]$ and $[-3,1,7]$ are l. i. then the spam has dimension $2$.

(2)$[L,3,5]=\lambda[1,0,-2]+\mu[-3,1,7]\iff\begin{cases}L=\lambda-3\mu\\3=\mu\\5=-2\lambda+7\mu\end{cases}$

which easily implies $L=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Find the determinant of the matrix formed by these vectors. The value at which the determinant vanishes is your desired value for $L$.